# Small image not fitting inside container despite adding fit property

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fit in a small pic inside a relatively larger container. I have used contain and cover properties yet they arent' affecting the results while i dont want to use fill property as it will affect quality of pic. I guess there is something minor am missing here if anyone can guide.

[image]

**my code:**

```
Positioned(
                    top: 200,
                    left: 200,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 400,
                      height: 300,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/full/3.jpeg',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain),
                )),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `BoxFit.cover` instead.
With it the image fills the given dimension, but keeping its aspect ratio.

Comment: i for the first time facing this issue, that both contain and cover not working

Comment: Can you maybe post the wrapping code of what you already posted?

Answer (score 0):

> **fill →** const BoxFit Fill the target box by distorting the source's
> aspect ratio.

[image]

> **contain →** const BoxFit As large as possible while still containing the
> source entirely within the target box.

[image]

> **cover →** const BoxFit As small as possible while still covering the entire target box.
>
> To actually clip the content, use clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge
> alongside this in a FittedBox.

[image]

> **fitWidth →** const BoxFit Make sure the full width of the source is shown, regardless of whether this means the source overflows the
> target box vertically.
>
> To actually clip the content, use clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge
> alongside this in a FittedBox.

[image]

> **fitHeight →** const BoxFit Make sure the full height of the source is shown, regardless of whether this means the source overflows the
> target box horizontally.
>
> To actually clip the content, use clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge
> alongside this in a FittedBox.

[image]

> **none →** const BoxFit Align the source within the target box (by default, centering) and discard any portions of the source that lie
> outside the box.
>
> The source image is not resized.
>
> To actually clip the content, use clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge
> alongside this in a FittedBox.

[image]

> **scaleDown →** const BoxFit Align the source within the target box (by default, centering) and, if necessary, scale the source down to
> ensure that the source fits within the box.
>
> This is the same as contain if that would shrink the image, otherwise
> it is the same as none.

[image]